# Using `Unpack` on `TypeVar`s to dynamically generate function signatures

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I'm trying to dynamically generate the function signatures for child classes of `_AbstractGameObject`. I have successfully experimented with `Unpack`ing the concrete `TypedDict`s in the child classes but wondered why I need to do that if can define the `Unpack` in the base class. However I get a mypy error at `_AbstractGameObject.load`. `D` is a `TypedDict` but it cannot be `Unpack`ed apparently. Am I expecting too much from this experimental feature or can it be done?

```
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generic, Self, TypedDict, TypeVar, Unpack

D = TypeVar("D", bound="_GameObjectDict")


class _GameObjectDict(TypedDict):
    name: str


class AssetDict(_GameObjectDict):
    path: Path


@dataclass
class _AbstractGameObject(ABC, Generic[D]):
    name: str

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, **kwargs: Unpack[D]) -> Self:  # <- error: Unpack item in ** argument must be a TypedDict  [misc]
        return cls(**kwargs)


@dataclass
class _GameObject(_AbstractGameObject[D], Generic[D]):
    def to_dict(self):
        return _GameObjectDict(name=self.name)


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Asset(_GameObject[AssetDict]):
    path: Path
```

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting - I think this probably can't be done directly, as Unpack only accepts TypedDict. I would agree though that a Generic with this bound should be acceptable. I would suggest raising it on the python discussion forums: https://discuss.python.org/

A discussion of this without the bound can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3187

For solving your issue, I would suggest use of pydantic, as this allows for generics. It also allows you to have an inheritance structure that allows for attributes to be in an any order: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/

For a simple inheritance structure it could also be done with dataclasses and to_dict.

Here's a version:

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generic, Self, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel


class _GameObjectDict(BaseModel):
    name: str

D = TypeVar("D", bound=_GameObjectDict)


class AssetDict(_GameObjectDict):
    path: Path


@dataclass
class _AbstractGameObject(ABC, Generic[D]):
    name: str

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, config: D) -> Self:
        return cls(**config.model_dump())


@dataclass
class _GameObject(_AbstractGameObject[D], Generic[D]):
    def to_dict(self):
        return _GameObjectDict(name=self.name)


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Asset(_GameObject[AssetDict]):
    path: Path
```

Comment: Thanks I had also been using the dicts themselves with success in the load method, I was interested in the kwarg unpacking though and how flexible that could make my api.